# A little issue with testing an ActionResult that returns a Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have an ActionResult like this:

```
public ActionResult AddDoc(StudentModel studentModel)
{

    var student = _studentHelper.GetStudent(studentModel, true);

    _updateStudentManager.UpsertStudent(student);

    return Json(new { result = true });
}
```

Test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calling_AddDoc_Returns_JsonResult()
{
    var studentModel = new StudentModel()
    {
        Name = "Jon",
        Id = "1"
    };

    var studentToAdd = new Student()
    {
        StudentId = "1",
        Name = "Jon",
        Course = "SomeCourse"
    };

    _studentHelper.Setup(x => x.GetStudent(studentModel, false)).Returns(studentToAdd);
    var res = _controller.AddDoc(studentModel) as JsonResult;

    Assert.AreEqual("{ result = True }", res.Data.ToString());
}
```

The GetStudent() just maps the incoming object to a new instance of Student and returns it.

The test fails with 'System.NullReferenceException'

Debugging the TestMethod shows that this line

```
    var student = _studentHelper.GetStudent(studentModel, true);
```

in the controller is not executing at all even when I tried to Step Into the method.

The 'student' object is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Setup call has an error. This call expects second parameter to be false.

```
_studentHelper.Setup(x => x.GetStudent(studentModel, false)).Returns(studentToAdd);
```

While you are calling from the controller with the value of true.

```
var student = _studentHelper.GetStudent(studentModel, true);
```

You are probably using loose behavior of Moq which makes it return null.